# Sort taxonomy by comment count

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I would like to sort my taxonomy posts by comment count but I can't seem to get it right. I am using the following piece of code. This does change the order but not to comment count. I am not sure what it is changing it too.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

if ( is_tax( 'profession' ) && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) )
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'comment_count' );

return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you took your answer from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23723/how-to-order-posts-by-descending-comment-count-on-taxonomy-page/23806), which was coded some 8 years ago and, I guess, no longer works? (Unless the taxonomy is `professions` and not `profession`?)

This is what I would try:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin()                        // Only target front end queries
        && $query->is_main_query()          // Only target the main query
        && $query->is_tax( 'profession' )   // Only target 'profession' taxonomy
    ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'comment_count' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
};
```